# "Table has no columns" in Google Charts PieChart

Tags: javascript, jsf, google-visualization

I'm using Java and JSF. The object I transform into a JSON passed to the `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` method is a list of maps.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Name", "Value");
map.put("A", new Random().nextInt());
map.put("B", new Random().nextInt());
listOfMaps.add(map);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String arrayJson = gson.toJson(listOfMaps);
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(" + arrayJson + "));");
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("piechart");
```

The HTML is:

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        function drawChart(mapList) {
            var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapList);
            var options = {
                title: 'Teste'
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(gdata, options);
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" autoUpdate="true"  globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
        <p:commandButton id="button" value="test" action="#{testMB.test()}" />
        <br />
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 600px" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Screenshot of the error in the page:

[image: Table has no columns.]

Nothing appears in the JavaScript console.

EDIT:

After changing the `List` from `Map` to `String[]`, then the chart is displayed. When I make a JavaScript alert, the array length is printed, but not the values.

Comment: When is this JavaScript function `drawChart(mapList)` supposed to be invoked? - How do you invoke it? It appears that it is never invoked. Put some debug statements or simply an `alert` box inside the function to see, if it is actually invoked or not with the correct value of `mapList`.

Comment: It is invoked. I "alerted" the `mapList`'s length, but when printing the values it's empty. And the chart is displayed with only one column named "Other". Only after I changed from `List` of `Map`s to `List` of `String` arrays.